# IllegalStateException: Same thread, different source (GUI)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, actionlistener, illegalstateexception

my problem is that I want to add the same ActionListener to 2 different components on my GUI program. One, when the user presses **Enter** Key in a JTextField, and the second when the user clicks on a JButton.  I am using the Netbeans IDE.

So I created a Thread, t1, and in the actionListener's actionPerformed method, I simply put *t1.start()*. Then I added the actionListener object to my JTextField and my JButton.
When I run the program, the first time I either click the button or press **Enter**, the program runs smoothly. But on the second time I click the button or press **Enter**, the program throws an **IllegalStateException**.
Here is my code:

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something
        }
     });
    public final ActionListener listener;

    public myClass () {    //Constructor 
        this.listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                t1.start();
            }
        };
    InitComponents();
    JButton.addActionListener(listener);      //Adding listener object to JButton.
    JTextField.addActionListener(listener);   //Adding listener object to JTextField.
    }
```

I am thinking that the thread did not 'die' from the first time I clicked or pressed **Enter**, even though the *run()* method already exited. I tested the program at different points to make sure that the *run()* method did exit.

I am able to make program work if I create a thread in both the *JButtonActionPerformed(* and *JTextFieldActionPerformed()* methods, and start them inside these methods itself. But it's redundant since I am writing the same actions to be performed in 2 different methods.

Any help on why the IllegalStateException exception was thrown and on how to create a single ActionListener for both the JComponents using a thread is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Threads are none-reentrant - that's fancy speak for, a thread can't be run more then once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) state...

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.
>   
> **Throws:**
>   IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.

You can not `start` a `Thread` twice.  Instead, start with a `Runnable` and wrap a new `Thread` around it each time you want to run it

Comment: I understand that it cannot be started twice, but I am sure the thread died before starting it again. I tested the program at different levels to make sure that the thread did exit.
Moreover, it it not the _IllegalThreadStateException_ that is being thrown, it is the _IllegalStateException_. Is there any specific difference here?

Comment: *"but I am sure the thread died before starting it again"* - Irrelevant, you CAN NOT start a `Thread` after it has been started, regardless if it has died or not, they are non-reentrant.  You need to create a new instance of the `Thread`, preferably using a `Runnable` to seed it

Comment: Thank you for helping out! I will read more on the documentation you quoted for more clarifications.